# How to access external file server from typo3?

Tags: typo3

I'm using typo3 and trying to make an extension that present some images that are stored in a file server. I'm considering to use curl to get the images and display them. But I will like to know what it will be the right approach.

Is it safe and ok to access the images from the external file server and present them through an extension, for example using something like curl?

Or should the images be stored on typo3 instead, using a webservice?

I need to use around 500 images which are updated daily, so I'm afaid that my typo3 installation is going to get full pretty easy with all those images.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution would put extra stress on the webserver and the file server. All those images that would be normally served by the webserver would involve initialization of the TYPO3, your code and the request on the file server.

There are then 2 things that you should consider and that answer your questions about security and whether copies of the images shall be saved on the webserver:

1. **Caching** - very desirable if not required so that the file server is not stressed. You should make a copy of the image on the webserver and keep serving that copy of the image. Obviously, they will take the disk space so you will have to prune the cache periodically and remove the cached images based on some criteria.
2. **Security** - You will have to implement measures that will guarantee that only an image that is part of the page can be displayed. You will also have to make sure that the fileserver is not exposed in any way.

I think that both things require that you track the images in the database so that you know which images are part of the pages, what is their original location on the fileserver, what is the lifetime of the copy and when it shall be removed, what is the fingerprint of the file so that you can track possible replacement of the image on the fileserver, etc. All in all, there will be issues that you will have to solve.